# Remove large file on Mountain Lion when disk is full

Tags: mac-osx

I ran a process that was writing stderr log messages to a file and didn't realize how fast the log file would grow.  The result is that the log file filled up the entire rest of my hard drive and now when I try to remove the file using `rm`, the computer freezes.  I'm running OS X Mountain Lion and my primary hard drive is 2TB.  The log file is consuming over 1TB of disk space.

Do I need to just let `rm` run for a long time to remove a 1TB file?  Should I just restore from a time machine backup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to zero the log file from the command line.

Something like `: > /path/to/file.log`

See: [Is there a way to delete 100GB file on Linux without thrashing IO / load?](https://serverfault.com/questions/336917/is-there-a-way-to-delete-100gb-file-on-linux-without-thrashing-io-load/336935#336935)

Comment: Any explanation for why this would be faster?

Comment: When there's no (other) write access to the file, truncate vs. unlink shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: I assumed the app was still writing.

Comment: This worked, although there was nothing still writing to the file (because the disk had completely filled up as a result of writing to it).  It's not clear to me why this worked and rm did not.

Comment: @RyanH Asking that question will only result in disparaging remarks about HFS and the Mac OS kernel's disk-scheduling algorithm (both of which SUCK and cause interactive performance to go to the sad place if you do something disk-intensive)

Comment: *shrug* Still a mystery, then.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what was happening in this case, but in general a file's space isn't freed until its last link is removed  (e.g. with `rm`) AND the last process that had it open closes it. If the process writing to it still had it open, `rm` won't have recovered the space -- but truncating it (e.g. with `: >`) will, even if it's still open in some other process.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to just let rm run for a long time to remove a 1TB file?

Yes. It's very likely that a file which filled up the disk is spread into fragments everywhere and the filesystem needs to adjust the free list entries for every single fragment. This takes a while.

> Should I just restore from a time machine backup?

This is an option. It's debatable whether it would take longer. If you think you might lose anything, just wait for `rm`.

Comment: I tried letting rm run for more than a day and it didn't finish and the computer was completely unresponsive.  The `: > file` approach finished within a few minutes.