# Fastest way to remove numerous big files

Tags: filesystems, ext3, cleanup

I have a directory with integration tests temporary files, which has the following structure:

```
TestTemp --- Test01 (~1.5TB)  --- Subdirectory01 (~100GB) -- Destination JSON (1-100MB)
                              --- Subdirectory02          -- Destination JSON files
                              --- Subdirectory03          -- Destination JSON files
                              ...
                              --- Subdirectory15 (about 10-15 dirs)

         --- Test02
         --- Test03
         ...
         --- Test15 (about 5-7 directories)
```

Total is around 10TB.

Filesystem is ext3, can't handle this directory as a drive. I was following [this article](http://www.slashroot.in/which-is-the-fastest-method-to-delete-files-in-linux), but this one more about big, but few files.

I tried to run 6 tests for each option: `find` and `exec rm -rf`, `find -delete` and that strange perl script one by one and then in parallel for two directories.

Perl thing worked the best (about 4 mins), next was `find -delete` (4.10) and then the first option with 4.50.

Parallelisation didn't give the expected results. All the options were working slower. And this was only two directories at the same time. I think, that giving more directories will cause even longer running time.

I didn't try GNU utility `parallel` as I have no root access (the cleanup script is run by Jenkins), so I couldn't install it.

What is the best option to remove numerous *big* files in *numerous* directories as fast as possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not obvious that you can get much better with the ext3 file system. See [these graphs](http://www.depesz.com/2010/04/04/how-to-remove-backups/) from a long investigation found on [this serverfault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/128012/how-to-make-rm-faster-on-ext3-linux). It took minutes no matter what they did.

[ext4 with extents or xfs is probably faster](http://www.bullopensource.org/ext4/20070404/FileDeletion.html)

If you are deleting an entire tree, and can dedicate a volume to it, you might script deleting the logical volume and recreating the file system every time.
If it comes to that you might as well experiment with a different file system though.